# Can ajax be fired when user don't use browser to visit the page?

Tags: javascript, ajax

For example, I have some ajax code in web page A that post something to page B whenever user visit page A. If the user isn't using browser to visit page A, is the ajax fired? (User maybe using ajax to post something to page A instead of using browser to visit, in this case, will the ajax code in page A be fired?)
I know JavaScript runs on browser so I guess the answer is no.

Comment: I'll assume by your question that page A and page B aren't on the same domain?

Comment: In general, you cannot rely on the HTTP client doing anything in particular with the content you send in response to a request.

Comment: @JohnGreen I just come up with this question, they don't really exist. But I'm curious about the difference if there are/aren't on the same domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If the user isn't using browser to visit page A, is the ajax fired?

Ajax has nothing to do with "visiting", i.e. loading, a page. Ajax means "sending a http request *from JavaScript code*". While loading page A means loading the inline js code, it is not automatically executed. Ajax does not automatically fetch linked resources (images, scripts, stylesheets), you'd have to do that manually, and execute the scripts explicitly if you want their ajax code to "fire".

Only a browser (with js enabled) does that by default. Your guess is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First, the ajax request will not be fired from your page A to your page B. When you make a [request](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html) or an [ajax request](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) you are sending a message from a **client** to a **server**.

Answering your question: no, if the javascript that makes the ajax request is in your page A, the request will be fired just when the user open the page A, unless you treat what you need on the server side, when you get the page.